# Click a button to change Views warning problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to click a button to change Views in iphone app . I use this code and it work , but there is 2 warning .

```
-(IBAction) showSearchFlye:(id)send;
{
    NSLog(@"Shoing Search flye");
    SearchFlye *search= [[SearchFlye alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchFlye" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:search animated:NO];

}
```

this is the warning message  http://hpics.li/fef7ba9 .

and this is the interface of the class SearchFlye

```
@interface SearchFlye : UIViewController  {

}

@end
```

The application work fine but i dont understand wy i have this warning ? And if it's correct to do this for changing view ?

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your warnings should come from not having imported the header file where `SearchFlye` is declared in the .m file where `showSearchFlye` is defined.

The reason why it works is this: compiler does not have information about your class, hence the warnings, but your class is linked in and it contains all the selectors that are needed by the objective-c runtime (which does a dynamic dispatch).

If this is the correct way of changing view, depends on your application UI architecture. If you don't need a navigation controller or a tab bar, it seems fine to me clicking on a button to move to another view...

Comment: I added the #import "FirstViewController.h" and there are no warnig now :) thank you

Answer (score -2):

hi please use @class classname in .h file of yours ..
create project with navigation based and try it to push like your second question or else add a rootviewcontroller from a main view controller and then try sending pushviewcontroller

and also Maybe you have @class UIPickerTable in your .h file and you did not have #import UIPickerTable.h on your {RootViewController}.m file

Comment: the second part of this answer is a copy/paste from this S.O. post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620661/receiver-classname-is-a-forward-class-and-corresponding-interface-may-not-exis (answer by bubjavier). Indeed, UIPIckerTable has nothing to do with what the asker is asking here.

Comment: @sergio : sir however instead of posting link directly i added this code both are same only right??...

Comment: When using the words of another person, make sure that you place them within quotes and provide a link to where they originally said them.  Otherwise, you are committing plagiarism.